# Finding Saddle Points

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

How many saddle points are on the graph of $h(x,y)=x^3-12xy+8y^3?$

I need to find the critical point of this function, but I get stuck when I have to find the partial derivatives of fx and fy.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Resource function: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/StationaryPoints/ -- If this is not a question about the software product Mathematica, use a different site.

Comment: Please edit the title since the final goal is `saddle points` instead of only `critical points`.

Comment: Done, thank you.

Comment: Was this intended for a different forum? It’s out of scope for Mathematica.SE.

Answer (score 7):

```
ClearAll[h]
h[x_, y_] := x^3 - 12 x y + 8 y^3

crit = {x, y} /. Solve[D[h[x, y], {{x, y}}] == 0, {x, y}, Reals]

ContourPlot[
  h[x, y], {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 3},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[crit]}
]
```

[image: contour plot and critical points]

---

I noticed that you seek only the *saddle* points. In that case adding another condition, that the Hessian be negative, will work directly:

```
saddle = 
  {x, y} /. 
    Solve[
      {
        D[h[x, y], {{x, y}}] == 0,
        Det[D[h[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}]] < 0
      }, 
      {x, y}, Reals
    ]

(* Out: {{0, 0}} *)
```

Comment: Cool. I had no idea that Solve would accept this `{3 x^2 - 12 y, -12 x + 24 y^2} == 0` as a first argument.  I've been doing this `Thread[D[h[x, y], {{x, y}}] == {0, 0}]` for years.

Comment: @Craig It may be a recent-ish addition (a few years ago?), but I can't recall where I picked it up.

Answer (score 7):

```
f = x^3 - 12 x y + 8 y^3;
sol = Solve[Grad[f, {x, y}] == 0, {x, y}, Reals](*CriticalPoints*)
{{x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> 2, y -> 1}}

hesse = D[f, {{x, y}, 2}] /. sol[[1]](*Hessian*)
{{0, -12}, {-12, 0}}

Det@hesse
-144
```

Det@hesse < 0   =>  {x->0, y->0} is Saddlepoint

```
Show[
 Plot3D[f, {x, -2, 3}, {y, -2, 3}, Mesh -> {100}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, PlotTheme -> "FilledSurface"],
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize@Large, Point[{x, y, f} /. sol]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) or directly `f = x^3 - 12  x  y + 8  y^3;
Solve[{Grad[f, {x, y}] == 0, Det[D[f, {{x, y}, 2}]] < 0}, {x, 
  y}, Reals]`

Comment: Did you solve it with Symply in Python?
I just want to know how I can do it by myself.

Comment: @cvgmt I wanted to do it step by step, because it's a new contributor. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Ioivz Do you have Mathematica?

Comment: Nope! Too expensive! I'm learning to solve it with symply and python which is free... :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done automatically  by

```
ResourceFunction["StationaryPoints", 
ResourceSystemBase -> "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/api/1.0"]
[x^3 - 12 x y + 8 y^3, {x, y}, "SaddlePoints"]
```

> `{{0, {x -> 0, y -> 0}}}`